Does making the Moonstone Axe's Special faster decrease how long it blocks damage?
The Moonstone Axe's Special acts as a block, negating damage for a brief period of time. If I get a Boon that increases the speed of my Special, such as Hermes's Swift Flourish or Chaos's Flourish, will that decrease how long the Special will block damage?

As this game is Early Access does this not fall into the 'unreleased games' rule? Or avoids it because it's a form of release

@Neon1024 An early access game is considered a released game and is on-topic. See the [meta] post: When is a game publicly available?

It won't affect the blocking time.
When you start loading your special, it activates something like an indefinite shield that will stay there for a few milliseconds even if you end up canceling your special, no matter your special speed. So at the time you start using your special, this shield is activated, and from there a time window independent of your special charging speed is used to determine its lifespan. So no matter the speed of your special, it will affect the special itself, not the blocking time coming with your special. You can still build around special speed for the Moonstone Axe.
You could even see it this way: the faster you can use your special, the quicker you can activate it again and get this possibility to block again. So building around speed is beneficial.

I can't tell if you're saying speed does or doesn't affect block time.

Sorry if the answer was unclear, I clarified it.
